# Is there a way to change the html head section of a Google site?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I would like to include some Share Buttons from ShareThis.com in my Google-Site. ShareThis created this code to be included in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>
```

To get it into my Google-Site, I wrote this program with Google-Apps-Script and executed it:

```
function myFunction() {
  var headers = {"A": "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var switchTo5x=true;</script>",
                 "B": "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js\"></script>",
                 "C": "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js\"></script>"};

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("sites.google.com/site/mysitename/home",
                {"headers": headers, "method": "post"});
}
```

There appeared no error message, but it will show no result in the site's source-code.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Is _share this_ the only option? Because There is a way to do it with _Add this_. There is a special gadget to insert for the _add this_ option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jacobvdb. Indeed, I am using Add this already, as you can see on my Google Site in my profile, but I would like to display some counters if possible. Please tell me your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not allow editing of the head section. Free service has its limits. Shame. I would like to add some script also.